# Box plot with previously calculated values

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have the following data I calculated previously:

```
plotData <- structure(list(Min = c(250.866197946263, 270.805621355386), `2.5%` = c(1806.60435406315, 
1807.31835620068), `50%` = c(7660.214866495, 7667.78371852935
), mean = c(8598.13903058242, 8600.3276561399), `97.5%` = c(20678.7670144642, 
20675.0354903488), Max = c(35526.3400756986, 36782.0082581976
)), .Names = c("Min", "2.5%", "50%", "mean", "97.5%", "Max"), row.names = c("median", 
"mean"), class = "data.frame")

    > plotData
            Min     2.5%      50%     mean    97.5%      Max   Type
median 250.8662 1806.604 7660.215 8598.139 20678.77 35526.34 Median
mean   270.8056 1807.318 7667.784 8600.328 20675.04 36782.01   Mean
```

What I want to do is use ggplot to plot each row as a box plot with an extra line at the mean and then do a factor on the Type. So if I had a plot `p` for the first row, I can complete it using:

`p + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(Type)))`

However it seems that ggplot only plots it if you provide the raw data that I don't have. Is there a way to get the boxplot directly from the summary statistics in ggplot2?

I've also tried to do it with geom_errorbar but without much success...

Thanks!

Comment: This is confusing. What do you mean by "for the first row?" What's the first row?

Comment: the first row corresponds to the row with "Type = Median". Basically, I have two estimates, one using the median value of the parameters and one using the mean value. Each estimate itself is stochastic which generates all the information on each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example on the [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_boxplot.html) one what you're after. Basically you should set the `stat` to `"identity"`.

Using your data, you can get something like this:

```
row.names(plotData) -> plotData$X1; 
ggplot(plotData, aes(x = X1, ymin=Min, lower=`2.5%`, middle = `50%`, upper = `97.5%`, ymax = Max)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

[image]

To add the line for the mean, the only way I'm aware of, is to do it in a rather "hacky" fashion.

```
ggplot(plotData, aes(x = X1, ymin=Min, lower=`2.5%`, middle = `50%`, upper = `97.5%`, ymax = Max)) + 
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(x=X1, y=mean), label="__________________________________", color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there also an easy way to add the horizontal bars to the whiskers? Your very neat trick of `geom_text(aes(x=ParamEstim, y=Min), label="_________", color="red")` gives something that doesn't quite line up ?

Comment: I suppose you could add whiskers the same way I have done it above, `geom_text(aes=ParamEstim, y=Min), label="____")`. And the line doesn't quite line up. Unfortunately I'm not aware of any other way to do it within the `ggplot` world.